# Present simple with "that" vs. a participle

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns, participle-clauses

I know the subordinate conjunction *that* is often omitted. Here are two sentences:

> 1. Select the course containing the exercises you want to repeat.
> 2. Select the course contains the exercises you want to repeat.

The first one sounds correct to me, but not the second. I have a strong feeling that the second should be

> Select the course **that** contains the exercises you want to repeat.

Is it really so, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *that* can be omitted from a relative clause **except when the relativised noun phrase functions as the subject of the relative clause**:

> He was the person I saw/that I saw

but

> He was the person that saw me.

> **He was the person saw me* is not grammatical in standard Englishes, though it is possible in some dialects.

So in your example

> Select the exercises the course contains.

would be possible, because the exercises are the object of "contains" in the relative clause; but not **Select the course contains the exercise*.

It is nothing to do with the tense, and in fact your question has nothing whatever to do with tense. It's true that one of the uses of the *-ing* participle is to create a  continuous tense, but **only** when it follows a part of the auxiliary *be*. Here there is no such auxiliary, and no continuous tense: only a participial clause introduced by *containing*.

When you use this participial clause it is replacing the relative clause, so you cannot use the relativiser *that* (or a relative pronoun such as *which*).

Answer (score 2):

**that contains** can be expressed as **containing.**

So, it can only be left out if you use the participle form in this case.

containing is not present continuous, it is a participial phrase.

Present continuous is: is containing and cannot be used here.

Comment: Thanks. So it will be better to change the title of this question to "Omitting 'that' when we change the time from present participle to present simple"?

Comment: Present simple with that versus a participle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your No. 2 in the slightly modified way: *"The folder "Select the course" contains the exercies you want to repeat"*. It has become possible because the verb in the form of Present Indefinite *(contains)* needs a subject which is represented now by NP "The folder "Select the course...".

In your No. 2 the relative clause *"...contains the exercies (you want to repeat)"*, which is also complex, must have its own subject - relative pronouns **that** or **which**.

As you can see the relative pronoun *"that"* is omitted (it can be only with defining relative clauses) in the relative [complex] clause (where "...that you want to repeat" is a relative clause itself) because this pronoun refers to the object, i.e. it is not a subject.

Taking this into account No. 2 may be expanded into: *"Select the course which contains the exercies that you want to repeat"*.